# Вопрос про тег img и base64

Tags: php, html

Можно ли как то через src в `<img src="/test.php" alt="">` получить ответ в base64
 и вывести изображение

Comment: можно. что бы было красиво, сделайте `<img src="/test.png" alt="">` , в htaccess переведите `test.png` на `test.php` и в php обработайте base64

Comment: @Saidolim напишите ответом с примером .htaccess добавлю кармы

Comment: только один момент уточните смысл `получить ответ в base64 и вывести изображение`

Comment: @Saidolim да вы правильно меня поняли получить в ответ base64 и вывести изображение, запрос должен отправить src

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется просто отдавать из файла .php картинку, надо не забыть

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Если планируете отдавать браузеру base64, то получится плохо - браузер как-то не очень понимает base64 в качестве файла, да и сам файл раздуется на треть при кодировании в этот вид.

А вот если хочется вставить мееелкую картинку, то тут вообще надо на этапе генерации страницы не ссылку на картинку вставить, а саму картинку (только не забывайте правильно указать gif/jpg/png mime тип), [такой код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL):

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,___а_тут_собственно_кодированное в b64__" />
```

Если хочется работать с картинкой средствами броузера и внезапно хочется base64, то ответ уже [пролетал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
$binary = base64_decode($base64_image);
$image= imagecreatefromstring($binary);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```